# Notification id for every user

Tags: android

I have a chat app,if user receives new message i am creating new notification.My problem starts here.I want to create 1 notification for each user.I mean I don't want to create new notification for every message.

**Example:**

```
1)User A sends message to User B
2)User B receives notification
3)If user A sends one more message,User B's phone don't create new notification because it created for previous message.
```

So `uniqueId` should be special for each user.But how can I store them ? What is the best way to do this ? I think about store in database but I am not sure.What do you suggest ?

```
mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have an id for every user in your database - use that as the notification id to make notifications unique at the user level.